# What kind of metadata can be stored in m4a files?

Tags: metadata, m4a

I have a collection of voice recordings from my Android phone, all stored in `.m4a` files. I would like to know the date of the recording, but the file timestamps have all been set to the date at which I extracted the files from the phone.

When I play them in Totem, the metadata sidebar shows the correct year (e.g. 2013), which leads me to think there must be some metadata stored in the file. It's not just showing the current year, or the year of the file timestamp.

Neither `mutagen-inspect` nor `puddletag` reveal any tags.

What metadata can an `m4a` file hold and how do I get at it?

Comment: m4a is an audio-only mpeg-4 and can have metadata allowed by the mpeg-4 specification. I have never dug out the docs, but it appears to be extensible, so theoretically, you can embed arbitrary metadata

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What metadata can an m4a file hold and how do I get at it?

> **Metadata for .m4a apple lossless (ALAC) files**
>
> My new music library is all nicely ripped Apple Lossless files in .m4a
> containers. These contain metadata, but it’s not id3v2 and the
> universe of mp3 tools mostly don’t work. ffmpeg’s ffprobe sort of
> works but doesn’t show all tags.
>
> What does work for displaying m4a metadta is [mp4v2](https://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/), installable
> via Homebrew. [Docs here](http://mp4v2.googlecode.com/svn/doc/trunk/ToolGuide.html). It seems pretty stable but still gets
> some updates.
>
> ```
> (imac) = mp4file --list test.m4a
> BRAND  COMPAT              SIZING  FILE
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> M4A    M4A,isom,mp42       32-bit  test.m4a
>  
> (imac) = mp4info test.m4a
> mp4info version 1.9.1
> test.m4a:
> Track   Type    Info
> 1   audio   alac, 260.806 secs, 562 kbps, 44100 Hz
>  Name: Pastourelle (E passo de dossai: Ah! viens pres de moi), folksong for voice & orchestra (Chants d'Auvergne, Series 2, No. 1)
>  Artist: Dawn Upshaw
>  Composer: Joseph Canteloube
>  Release Date: 1994
>  Album: Canteloube: Songs of the Auvergne
>  Track: 1 of 15
>  Disk: 1 of 1
>  Genre: Vocal Music
>  BPM: 0
>  Part of Compilation: no
>  Cover Art pieces: 1
>  Album Artist: Kent Nagano
>  Media Type: Movie
>  TV Episode: 0
>  TV Season: 0
> ```

Source [Metadata for .m4a apple lossless (ALAC) files](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/metadata-for-m4a-apple-lossless-alac-files/)

Comment: Thank you for the lead. This is the correct software. I installed v2.0.0 on Ubuntu with `apt-get install mp4v2-utils` and used `mp4file --dump`. The `creationTime` element of the `moov.mvhd` section is the creation time in Macintosh Date Format, [specified here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap4/qtff4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH206-CJBIBAAE) and [convertible to readable format here](http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/mac-timestamp.php)

Answer (score 2):

Mp3tag (http://www.mp3tag.de) is a universal tag editor which can tag mp3 and mp4 (including m4a) formats. Pls check.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a more recent/maintained project called [AtomicParsley](https://github.com/wez/atomicparsley) that is very interesting. It also allows you to edit MP4/M4A metadata.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new freemium muti-tool for windows available on https://audiozip.net
which shows always all frames inside mp4/m4a-files and many others.
Of course it allows editing too and personal data can be easily removed there.
It’s a complete music manager software!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).